# How do I determine the shutter count on a EOS 60D body?

Tags: canon, canon-60d, shutter-actuations

I'm selling a 60D body, and I want to check the reported shutter-release count. But I can't find it on the menu anywhere. Does someone know how to find it?

Note that the next assigned filename is not it. It notes the largest numbered file on the card and jumps ahead to that, so the numbers continued from my previous camera body.

Comment: I think if you take a raw picture with it, in its data you find find the photo number.

Comment: Canon does not include the shutter count in the EXIF info. It is stored internally but Canon has not officially released any way for consumers to access it. There are varying third party software applications that can retrieve it from some models. Which particular models will vary from one third party software application to the next.

Comment: I have Magic Lantern on it. Would that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Magic Lantern installed you can check the shutter count on your 60D. All you need to do is install Magic Lantern on your EOS, press MENU and then DISP. The shutter count will appear at the bottom of the screen.

Another way to find the shutter count on many EOS models, including the 60D, is to use ShutterCount. You can download it from the developer's page [here](http://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/). It is not free, but the cost is very modest ($3.99 USD or less as of December 1, 2016).

For more detailed information about the current status of ShutterCount and what cameras it currently works with, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/80635/15871) to [How to check actuation count on an EOS 80D?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80630/15871)

Answer (score 2):

I have used camera info v1.2 writen by Magic_h200.
The utility is great to retrieve some info. The more interesting was the shutter count.
My utility is based on, with a access to edit owner, artist and copyright text. You can also synchronise the date/time of the canera within the local time on pc.
I am Mourad Mkhakh the author of this tool.
This is the new version
Portable:
https://app.box.com/s/5qr2uvi81ypp2y45den3pes7u6l2796g
Install version:https://app.box.com/s/2b04mw7tpuo1dkzvvg2po2lseu9ohg3f

Comment: A new version is released with a nice interface, you can get it at sourceforge website.
This video on youtube describe how to use it and how to check actuation counter.
https://youtu.be/-GGFdbagn-M.

Answer (score 0):

by the way for windows users, i am using this utility, Eos Digital Info;
you can get some infos like owner name and lense mounted on the camera, and you can also update date time or modefy the copyright text.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wetBW2pjaxdWkwRHNKNEYxYjQ
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you write this software? It is okay to refer to your own projects or software, but please disclose your authorship when you do promote it.

Comment: The year-old Accepted answer already mentions *EOSInfo* as a Windows-only program.

Comment: @JDługosz the software mentioned/written by Ikossan/Mourad Mhkakh is not the same as *EOSInfo* written by David P. at astrojargon.net

Answer (score -1):

I have OnOne photo raw 2017 you may read the EXIF data for any photo. The shutter actuations will be in the file name.

Comment: Odd way to name a file… can you explain better?

Comment: That doesn't work with Canon EOS cameras because the shutter count is not included in the maker notes section of the EXIF info like  it is by *some* other cameras.

Answer (score -1):

The number of shutter actuations on older Canon cameras is encoded in the 'Image Number’. On my 10D, it shows 2929222 approaching 3 million shots which is clearly wrong. One EXIF data tool reports the number as 292-9222. That makes more sense – the last image was IMG_9222.JPG. I then realised that the first 3 digits are in fact the folder number on the memory card.

Under DCIM there are two folders at present: 291CANON and 292CANON. The folders each hold 100 files so the first 3 digits increment once every 100 images to reflect the new folder number while the last 4 digits increase to 9999 then rollover to 0. A twist is that looking at one of the early images I took with this camera is that the folder numbers start at 100 rather than 0. Thus to convert the image number to the number of shots taken we need to do the following:

1. Split the image number into two parts: the last 4 digits (call this file number) and the first three folder number. We then need to do a bit of arithmetic.
2. Shutter Count = (folder number-100)*100 + modulo 100 file number. Modulo 100 may sound frightening, but in reality it means just take the two right hand digits.

So for my 10D
Shutter Count = (292-100)*100 +22 = 19200 +22 = 19222 shutter operations

Newer cameras store more images in each folder, so the mathematics change.

Comment: I think the count can be reset.  There is an option to count continuously or to start over on each empty memory card.  Also, it tracks the actual high number in the card so you can make it jump ahead if you put files there with those names.

Comment: It's also the case that if a memory card that was already used in another Canon camera is inserted and used the file numbers will jump to the next available number after the last image written to the card by the previous camera..