# Why are images from my brand-new Canon camera numbered starting in the 9000s instead of from 0001?

Tags: canon, dslr, canon-80d

I just bought the brand-new Canon 80D from Amazon, along with new memory card 64GB. When I took the first few pictures, I see that the file names start from "IMG_9545.jpg", "IMG_9546.jpg" and so on ...

I suppose that if the brand-new camera with new memory card, then the pictures should start from "IMG_0001.jpg". I also formatted my card.

Does that mean my Camera already used? Or is it the normal way how file names should be?

Comment: Did you use a card that was previously used in a camera? In this case, the count would just continue. Formatting the card after the first photo is taken would not affect the counter.

Comment: Somewhere in the depths of the menus there is a shutter count, just to be sure

Comment: @PlasmaHH please post the location of that in the menu as an answer. You may wish to [read this first though](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80630/how-to-check-actuation-count-on-an-eos-80d/).

Answer (score 24):

It turned out that I did insert another memory card, whose last number was `IMG_9544`, that's why when I insert new memory card, it starts from there, as @PhilipKendall suggested.

Thanks for all inputs, I know more about settings of camera.

Answer (score 9):

I have never seen this behavior in a new camera - mine always started with `IMG_0001` <sup>Not all had `IMG` as prefix</sup>. [An article on Canon Professional Network about file numbering and naming](https://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/storage_and_archiving/file_numbering_and_naming.do) states:

> EOS digital cameras offer you a choice of file number systems - continuous or auto reset. Which you choose will depend on how you like to work.
>
> Continuous numbering, as the name suggests, numbers each new image in sequence from 0001 to 9999.

So it would seem that your camera was used before. However, the only way to be certain about this <sup>(as far as I know)</sup> is to [check the 80D's actuation count](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80630/how-to-check-actuation-count-on-an-eos-80d/).

---

If you do not care about it, you can always [manually reset the file numbering (pp. 184-185 in the 80D's manual)](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300022720/01/EOS_80D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf#page=184):

> When you reset the file numbering manually, a new folder is created 
>   automatically and the file numbering of images saved to that folder 
>   starts from 0001.

---

Another possibility (and the answer in this case, as we learned) is that your memory card was not new and/or formatted. If the card already contains a file that is named `IMG_9544.JPG`, then your camera, as a way to preserve these already existing images, will start at `IMG_9545.JPG`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have seen a new Canon start from a different number - but that was when I used a memory card which had been used in a (different) Canon camera. I was up to `IMG_5645` or something on the old camera, and the new camera started at `IMG_5646`.

Comment: Hi @PhilipKendall: I just edited my question. And according to your input, it might be the reason?!

Comment: Yep, that's it. Once it saw a card with `IMG_9544` on it, it will restart its numbering from there. At this point, you are probably encouraged to [answer your own question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @PhilipKendall Although being the reason, OP's statement of a `new memory card` was the reason that I did not suspect that.

Answer (score 3):

In general terms, 9545 is a bit of a strange number to start at for a brand new camera. It's possible that the camera could have continued numbering from a photo that already existed on the memory card, however if you purchased the memory card at the same time as the camera and formatted it in the camera before taking any photos, this seems rather unlikely.

The usual way to check whether your camera truly is new would be to find the shutter count reported by your camera to see the actual number of photos it has taken. Unfortunately it's not possible to view this information directly on the Canon 80D.

The easiest method would be to try uploading one of the photos you have taken to a website such as [CameraShutterCount](https://www.camerashuttercount.com/), but (as noted in Michael Clark's comment) this method only works if the manufacturer provides the shutter count in the exif data encoded into the image which Canon apparently don't for the 80D.

There are some alternative suggestions for how to get the shutter count for the 80D in the question linked from [flolilolilo's answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/100457) if you really want to look this up, although it seems Canon don't like to make it easy, so it's a good thing you were able to figure out what happened.

Comment: There is nothing in the maker notes section of the EXIF info for .cr2 or .jpg files generated by Canon cameras to indicate shutter count. Thus, none of the websites that glean such info from uploading a photo will work for photos made using Canon cameras.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. It seemed worth a try since (at the time) it seemed the only memory card used with the camera had been a blank one, and so there might have been a chance the camera wasn't new. I missed the more relevant question that flolilolilo linked.