# Canon T3I Shutter sometimes will not work

Tags: canon, shutter

My Canon T3I on occasions will not take a picture.  I will snap a shot then try again giving adequate time and it will fight me on taking the picture or just not release the shutter at all no matter what I do even though I as pressing the button.  At times I have to give up on it all together and use something else to get the shot.  I though battery voltage and that is not it brand new batteries in it.  It is about 4 1/2 yrs old still original parts.  I am hoping the shutter is not dying but it seems this may be the issue.  I do not currently know the count on it but it has to be up near 80k by now. I am not a professional but I do enjoy photography and this thing comes everywhere with me.  Any opinions?

Comment: What lens(es) are you using? What is the lens(es)' minimum focus distance? What is your subject distance?

Comment: What shooting mode is the camera in? What happens if you switch to M mode?

Comment: [How do I determine the shutter count on a EOS 60D body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62381/1772) may be helpful for determining the shutter count.

Comment: Does the camera focus? It is not unusual for camera to refuse to shoot if the focus has not been achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have focus priority or shutter release priority?  Do you have a filter on the lens that may effect focus?  Is there a pattern to when this happens?  One pattern I have seen is taking a camera from an air conditioned vehicle into a hot summer day.  This can create a slight condensation on the filter which prevents the autofocus from locking in.  If you have focus priority this can be an issue.

Comment: Also worth noting here that auto mode uses focus priority, so a lot of people may be using it without knowing anything about what "focus priority" means.